# use class template in its definition

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, why no recursive instantiate

```cpp
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
  static constexpr T value = v;
  using value_type         = T;
  using type               = integral_constant<T, v>;  // no recurse?
  constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept {
    return value;
  }
  constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept {
    return value;
  }
};

int main() {
  integral_constant<long, 1>       l;
  integral_constant<long, 1>::type use_type;
  return 0;
}
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sddYz1)
[cpp insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/49046be2)

I think [this comment by pasbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568945/use-class-template-in-its-definition?noredirect=1#comment114171073_64568945) has answered this question.

Comment: @AlexF I updated the code to use to **type** and it still works.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't work?

Comment: It'd work even if `type` was used. The thing is, it is only instanciated as far as it is required (i.e., the last `type` is not used and hence not instanciated), hence there is no infinite recursion happening, it stops after the last one that is explicitly used. https://godbolt.org/z/9jKdxr

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought it may have an infinite recursion

Comment: @pasbi can you post an answer so that I can mark it accepted and close this question?

Comment: @maidamai I'd rather wait until some language lawyer comes around, I'm just doing educated evidence-based guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does result in infinite recursion, you can use
`integral_constant<long, 1>::type::type::type` as many times as you like.

This isn't a problem though as the compiler only instantiates templates that you are using not all the templates that you could possibly use.

You would have an error if you tried to declare a member recursively:

```
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
  static constexpr T value = v;
  using value_type         = T;
  using type               = integral_constant<T, v>;
  type member;
  constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept {
    return value;
  }
  constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept {
    return value;
  }
};
```